# can't change a UILabel text value inside a programmatically created custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, custom-view

So first of all I created a custom view that has a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` in it.

the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageText : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ImageText *view;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *money;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@end
```

here is the .m file for it

```
    #import "ImageText.h"

    @implementation ImageText

    - (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
            self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageText" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

So there's that `setLabelText` method. I declared it in the header file. I want to be able to create this customview and then change the `UILabel`'s text.

In my `ViewController`'s `.m` I do this:

```
ImageText *it = [[ImageText alloc] init];
[it.money setText:@"a"];


[_innercontent insertSubview: it belowSubview:_alishead];

[it setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:it attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:59.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: it attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:21.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_alishead attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:it
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_alishead attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:it
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

it creates the View and puts it where I want to with the following code but the `setLabelText` method does nothing at all. I tried doing something like:

```
it.money.text = @"a";
```

This doesn't seem to work either. How can I change this text?

I tried removing the setter, tried making them strong instead of weak I tried [it.money setText:@"a"]; but none of it works.

Comment: Is there something loaded other than the change of text? Like do you see your custom view loaded with the label maybe saying "label"?

Comment: @user1967709 yes, it is loaded as "Label" by default, what does that mean?

Comment: Oh i'm just making sure that you got the interface you expected vs a blank view with no label..I'm assuming you load your view from a xib file, correct?

Comment: any reason why you have a setter, `- (void)setLabelText:(NSString*)string;` have you tried `[it.money setText: @"a"];` ?

Comment: I did try what you said and it still doesn't change anything

Comment: I got nothing other than sharing ur project, or sample project with the same outcome, and just check it out in case something is missing

Answer (score 0):

Check that the IBOutlet in the .h file are correctly linked to the UILabel in the xib file

Comment: have you checked the IBOutlet?

Comment: I did, they work fine, in fact I am able to change the text from within the custom view's .m file but not from my view controller

Comment: wait, your problem i guess that is that 
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
is never called.
Infact, in your controller you call 
ImageText *it = [[ImageText alloc] init]

Comment: Try substituting initWithFrame, with -(id)init, or calling ImageText *it = [[ImageText alloc] initWithFrame: ...... ];

Comment: I changed it to -(id)init as you said but nothing changed. And then tried  [[ImageText alloc] initWithFrame: ...... ];  and still nothing changed. as far as I know calling init also calls initwithframe anyway, that's why I am able to see the view itself but I for some reason can't change the label text.

Comment: mmm, last try :) , remove this from the initialization method :   

if (self.subviews.count == 0)

.... otherwise I don't know. Hope you will find your answer, let me know in the case; :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing same thing and finally it works. Below is my code

```
if (self) {
        self=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOUR_NIB_NAME" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
return self;
```

Both will work either you initialize with **init or initwithframe**

Hope it helps

Comment: I actually had high hopes trying this, but sadly it didn't work either

Comment: it didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: Remove that check of if loop. I ran it and is working fine in my code. That self.subviews.count thing

Comment: I just removed and tried it and it still doesn't work, how is it that it works for you and not for me, what am I doing wrong here? I am trying exactly what you tell me to

Comment: how do you change the text of the label inside the custom view? maybe I am doing that wrong? because I have no problem with loading the xib file, I just can't change the text

Comment: T_DrawerCell *cell=[[T_DrawerCell alloc] init];
    [cell.lblDrawerTitle setText:@"Temp String"];
    LOG_String(cell.lblDrawerTitle.text)   . Remove that setter method you have writter. Prperties automativally generates those method. Try above code

Comment: thats exactly what I am doing, I'll lose my mind, I tried it both ways

Comment: did you try removing the your own setter?

Comment: yes, I did try that too just now, did everything you said till now

Comment: Dont know why that code is trolling. Have a look again. Else share some more current code so that i can figure out. And dont use "_" use self.  There is a lot of difference between them.

Comment: I just added all the relative code that I have about this, I really checked everything, I am starting to lose hope already, but I would appreciate it if you just had another look at it. It's most probably something tiny and stupid

Comment: Remove that setter method. By default those method exist

Comment: Cant help then :(. Working fine in me. There could be some issue with outlet connection. Check if the money label is connected to your view from inspector window

Answer (score 0):

Out of your code snippet is clear that you defined nib loading in method initWithFrame: but you're creating instance of your view with plain alloc-init. You have to create it using `[[ImageText alloc] initWithFrame:#someFrameOrZeroFrame]`. Otherwise your nib will never get load.

Comment: that's the thing it's not about that, the nib gets loaded without problem, I just can't change the text for some reason. init already calls initwithframe inside itself, but just to check it I tried what you said, it still didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

well when adding the views to the header file you should choose the view instead of the `File's Owner` option. Weird how it said that I should choose the file's owner in the tutorials I watched.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be wrong reference to the UILabel i.e Money. Give a tag of 100 to the label and try setting the text to the label by viewwithtag.

UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
label.text = @"Your text";

In your case, self.view is the object of ImageText.